# Ruby and Rails Installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, curl, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby and rails at once using curl with the following command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable    --rails
```

However I'm getting the following error

```
curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I've been using a proxy on my university network but I've removed the settings on the network proxy settings menu since i'm on another network

Comment: Well it seems your proxy is still activated

Comment: I'm trying to do a reinstallation of ruby and rails since i had them previously installed

Comment: Its not activated because I can push to github and I haven't set a proxy for git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

and then proceed with your installation. If it works, find in your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile or similar line saying something like

```
export HTTPS_PROXY = 'your_proxy_url'
```

and delete it.